# How to know the api version and the android source code

Tags: android, android-source, android-api-levels

I download the android source code here : https://github.com/android

But my problem is how to know the api version of each branch, like for exemple for the branch:

- gingerbread-release
- ics-mr0-release
- ics-mr1-release
- jb-release
- kitkat-release
- lollipop-mr1-release
- lollipop-release
- marshmallow-mr1-release
- marshmallow-mr2-release
- marshmallow-release
- nougat-release
- etc..

Answer (score 2):

Although you can download the source code directly from the different git repos it's comprised of, I would recommend using the [repo](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html) tool as it allows easier management. You can find a helpful setup guide on their website [here.](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)

As for the original question, Google posts all code names and tags on [this](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html) page. You should be able to match any version or API level you are looking for to a corresponding branch.

Comment: hmm sorry no i didn't find :( for exemple with api version is ics-mr0-release ? API level 15 or API level 14 ?

Comment: If you look at the top table there is code name version, version number, and API level. The second table has branch names with the version code name they belong to. So if you match the top table row to the second table row using the version code name you can determine the API level.

Comment: sorry i can't find  ics-mr0-release :(

Comment: You can use [this table](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) together with the other one. So, "ics-mr0-release" of course is some of the Ice Cream Sandwich releases and as it says "MR0" it's the original one even though it's not always referred to as "MR0" everywhere. So it must be Android 4.0. And 4.0 is API level 14.